# Android no GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 defined?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, depth

I implemented shadow mapping in my android project with OpenGL ES 2.0 (using java, not the NDK).
I use eclipse adt 2014_07_02 version.

The symptom is that close objects do not cast shadows on the ground. After some trying i realized, that the 16bit depthbuffer, that is attached to the FBO, needs more precision.

I set up the depth buffer attachment like this:

```
GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
            GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
```

Now, the problem is that there seems to be no such constant as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`. I googled the actual enum code for it (33190), and replaced the GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 with that code, and everything worked fine, the shadows were fine and precise.

My question is that is it safe to use this code, that is not defined in the SDK, or this might not work on other phones?

my plan is to implement some try-catch mechanism using glGetError(), and fallback to the 16bit depthbuffer. Could this work at all?

Comment: Why not just create several emulators of other phones and try it?

Comment: that seems right i just wanted to know why isn't that constant defined (it's use is discouraged, it is not supported, etc.) i will try with a variety of phones and emulators and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` is not part of core ES 2.0. Using it will require a device that supports the [GL_OES_depth24 extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth24.txt). It contains the definition:

> DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES 0x81A6

Converted to decimal, this is the 33190 value you used. Since it worked on your device, it looks like it supports the extension. Which is not a huge surprise, since this is fairly widely supported. ES 3.0 requires support for 24-bit depth buffers, so any GPU that can support ES3 has the necessary hardware feature, and can choose to expose this format to ES 2.0 apps via the extension.

To make your code portable, the clean solution is to check for the presence of the extension. You can do that by calling `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, and check if `OES_depth24` shows up in the returned string.

Once you verified that the extension is supported, the definition of the value in the Android frameworks is `GLES11Ext.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES11Ext.html#GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES)).

Answer (score 1):

Its OpenGL|ES feature, not Android specific.

Literally (from kronos doc's) :

void **glRenderbufferStorage**( GLenum target,
    GLenum internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height);

*target:*

Specifies the renderbuffer target. The symbolic constant must be GL_RENDERBUFFER.

*internalformat*:

Specifies the color-renderable, depth-renderable, or stencil-renderable format of the renderbuffer. Must be one of the following symbolic constants: GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB565, GL_RGB5_A1, **GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16**, or GL_STENCIL_INDEX8.